SignalrR Hub Constant Dispose
I have an MS .NET SignalR configured. It is an internal HUB and is only connected via a desktop application. The Hub when created constantly gets disposed and when I attempt to communicate with a client from the hub I get an already disposed error. I can communicate from the client to the hub so is unclear why communicating from the hub to the client is failing. Does anyone have details of why this would occur?
My investigation did not identify the cause. The one thing I noticed was that the hub Dispose operation is called constantly [after a connection has been made]. There is only 1 connection request being made and on the client side the hub is not tripping any disconnect - so it appears still connected on the client. I checked the hub destructor and appears to never be called.
The following is how the hub is prepared (on server):
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddGrpc();
     
     services.AddCors(o =>
     {
         o.AddDefaultPolicy(b =>
         {
             b.WithOrigins(TargetURL)
                 .AllowCredentials()
                 .AllowAnyHeader();
         });
     });

     services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

     services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
     {
         hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
         hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
         hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
     });
 }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "oiStockPusherSite v1"));
    }

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(PolicyName);

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        //endpoints.MapControllers(); 
        endpoints.MapHub<TradingServiceHub>("/orderITSignalR", options =>
        {
            options.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling; // you may also need this
        });
    });            
}

The following is how the HUB is activated:
protected virtual bool PrepareTradeActivityHub(string TargetHub)
{            
    string TradeActivitySignalRURL = "";
    bool Res = false;

    lock (PreparingHub)
    {
        TradeActivitySignalRURL = Connection;

        if (!PrepareNewHub)
        {                   
            if (HubConnectionOld == null)
            {                        
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", string.Format("Prepare Trade Service Hub for {0}", TradeActivitySignalRURL), EventLogEntryType.Information);

                HubConnectionOld = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection(TradeActivitySignalRURL);
                HubConnectionOld.Closed += TradingClientHubConnection_Closed;

                ClientHubProxy = HubConnectionOld.CreateHubProxy(TargetHub);

                Task<bool> Result = TradingClientHubConnection_Connect();
                Result.Wait();

                if (!Result.Result)
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Failed to start Trade Service Hub", EventLogEntryType.Error);

                    StopHubConnection();
                }
                else
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Connected to Trade Service Hub", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    
                    Result = ClientHubProxy?.Invoke<bool>("Active");
                    if (Result != null)
                    {
                        Result.Wait();
                        Res = Result.Result;
                        CallCheckActivated();                                
                        HubConnected = true;
                    }
                    else
                        Res = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Check if Hub still connectedHub", EventLogEntryType.Information);

                Res = true;
                if (ClientHubProxy != null)
                {
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        if (ClientHubProxy != null)
                        {
                            EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Test calling Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Information);

                            Res = await ClientHubProxy?.Invoke<bool>("Active");

                            if (Res)
                            {                                        
                                CallCheckActivated();
                                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Successfully called Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Problem calling Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ).Wait();
                }
                else
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Hub not avaible - should be", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {                    
            if (HubConnectionNew == null)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", string.Format("Prepare Trade Service Hub for {0}", TradeActivitySignalRURL), EventLogEntryType.Information);

                HubConnectionNew = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(TradeActivitySignalRURL).Build();
                HubConnectionNew.Closed += StockPusherHubDisconnect;
               var Connect = StockPusherHubConnection_Connect();
                Connect.Wait();

                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Test calling Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Information);

                var Response = HubConnectionNew.InvokeAsync<bool>("Active").Result;
                if (!Response)
                {
                    HubConnectionNew = null;
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Problem calling Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    HubConnected = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Successfully called Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    Res = true;
                    HubConnected = true;
                    HubConnectionNew.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100000);
                    
                }                        
            }
            else
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Test calling Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Information);

                var Response = HubConnectionNew.InvokeAsync<bool>("Active").Result;
                if (!Response)
                {
                    HubConnectionNew = null;
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Problem calling Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    HubConnected = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Successfully called Hub Active operation", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    Res = true;
                    HubConnected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Res;
}

protected virtual async Task StockPusherHubConnection_Connect()
{
    Exception exception = null;
    Exception except = null;

    try
    {
        if (HubConnectionNew != null)
        {
            lock (PreparingHub)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", string.Format("Attempt to connect to Hub for {0}", Connection), EventLogEntryType.Information);

                var HubConnect = HubConnectionNew?.StartAsync();
                HubConnect?.Wait();
                HubConnect?.ContinueWith(
                    task =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (task != null && task.IsFaulted)
                            {
                                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Problem connecting to Hub for", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                                EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", task.Exception.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);

                                exception = task?.Exception;
                                except = exception?.InnerException;
                                while (except != null)
                                {
                                    except = except?.InnerException;
                                    if (except != null)
                                        EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", except.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                ).Wait();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

As an addition. I put together a test app that demoed this observation. It is available on
https://github.com/FutureInfinite/SignalRTest
There is an operation to call back to the clients in the app called
PostMessage
This operation cannot be called as the HUB appears to always be disposed. If you could try it out and see if you can determine why the hub is not active for longer periods would be great. The WPF application has a button that needs to be selected to activate the Hub.
thx
Peter

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

From your code Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection, it means you are using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, and your server is using ASP.NET Core SignalR.  They are incompatible, please use ASP.NET Core SignalR  on the client side. We should use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client package.

I adjusted my logic based on the previous comment. I have the following configuration
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub - server
and
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection - client
I believe this is what was specified. I am though still having problems communicating with the client from the server. The hub (on the server) gets created and is immediately disposed of (dispose is being called on the hub).  I have an operation that is attempting to call the clients of the server but when activated I get a hub is disposed error.

I did configure the hub to be active for a longer period of time so I assume the hub is active. Also, I mentioned previously that the hub constructor is constantly being called (as well as "dispose"). So it appears SignalR has the hub instantiation in some sort of loop. The client is only calling hub creation once.

@user23478542 Please try to enable Server-side logging and
.NET client logging, and reproduce the issue, then we can get the detailed logs. Please hide the sensitive information before sharing with us, thanks for your patience.

I activated logging and not seeing any logs that clarify what is going on. There are no logs occurring between Hub creation and dispose. I checked error based logs and Debug logs. Still, a question is why the hub is being disposed of immediately after it is being created.

I added a test app at
https://github.com/FutureInfinite/SignalRTest
question.
Mentioned it above in the question.
If you could use this test app to see what I'm seeing and indicate what I'm doing wrong that would be great.
One point - I see there are 2 types of  builders IHostApplicationBuilder and IHostBuilder. I am using IHostBuilder as this one appeares to work. IHostApplicationBuilder appears to be for a full web server, which I believe SignalR is supposed to run under - but appears not to work. The hub does not get activated.

@user23478542 Please kindly check the solution below, and tell me if it works for you, thanks

Hi Jason Pan. That did the job. Appears to work. Now need to review what you did to see what's different. thx.

After checking the suggested solution - the only difference is that the modification only constructs a HUB object on the server and has that active during the posting operation. Unclear why this works but apparently keeps a hub active for a longer period of time. To be honest I'm not really clear on why this is necessary. The documentation indicates when a hub is instantiated it will be active for at least 30 seconds - and my tests showed a dispose happening right after it was created!

OK - I see the use of a HubContext is the trigger that allows the hub to be used for communicating with clients. Appears this is how the hub is to communicate with the clients. I'm more familiar with the previous version of SignalR and had used hub-to-client communication before and I don't recall having to use this - or if so I don't remember using it.

In SignalR, the Hub class is transient. Each time a client connects or calls a Hub method, a new Hub instance is created and disposed after the request completes. Therefore, you should not start long-running tasks in the Hub constructor, as the Hub instance may be disposed before the task finishes, causing "already disposed" errors.
To make it easier for you to test, I will provide the full test code again, as follows, everything works well. You can run it directly.

Add new Background service, here is the project structure.

1.OrderITHub.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestClient
{
    public class OrderITHubProxy : BindableBase
    {
        #region "Properties & Attributes"                
        protected Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection ClientHubConnectionNew;
        protected static Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection ClientHubConnectionNewSinlge;
        protected bool UseSingle { get; set; } = false;

        protected Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection HubConnectionNew
        {
            get
            {
                if (UseSingle == null)
                    return ClientHubConnectionNew;
                else
                    return ClientHubConnectionNewSinlge;
            }
            set
            {
                //the use of a single hub connection requires
                //that the hub connecion is to the same HUB
                if (UseSingle == null)
                    ClientHubConnectionNew = value;
                else
                    ClientHubConnectionNewSinlge = value;
            }
        }

        //protected static Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.IHubProxy ClientHubProxy { get; set; } = null;
        protected static object PreparingHub = new object();
        protected bool Continue { get; set; } = true;
        protected bool ActivatingTradeInterface = false;
        protected static bool HubConnected = false;
        protected string Connection;

        public delegate void ClientHubActive();
        public event ClientHubActive ClientHubActiveated;

        private static System.Timers.Timer HubConnectionTimer;
        private static object WaitToActivateHub = new object();
        #endregion //"Properties & Attributes"

        #region "Lifetime"
        public OrderITHubProxy(
            string Connection,
            bool UseSingle = false
            )
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", string.Format("Start Hub connection for {0}", Connection), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);

            HubConnectionTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

            this.Connection = Connection;
            this.UseSingle = UseSingle;

            ///simple thread logic to start up 
            ///and maintain the connection
            ///to the trading interface
            //HubConnectionTimer.Elapsed += PrepareTradeActivityClient;            
            //HubConnectionTimer.Start();
            PrepareTradeActivityClient(null, null);
        }

        private void TestApp()
        {

        }

        ~OrderITHubProxy()
        {
            StopTradeClientInterface();
        }
        #endregion "Lifetime"

        #region "Operations"

        virtual protected void PrepareTradeActivityClient(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                   async () =>
                   {
                       while (Continue)
                       {
                           try
                           {
                               ActivateTradeClientInterface();
                           }
                           finally
                           {
                               ///5sec interval for trading interface refresh
                               Thread.Sleep(5000);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
               );

            //HubConnectionTimer.Interval = 5000;            
        }

        protected virtual bool PrepareTradeActivityHub()
        {
            string TradeActivitySignalRURL = "";
            bool Res = false;

            lock (PreparingHub)
            {
                TradeActivitySignalRURL = Connection;

                if (HubConnectionNew == null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", string.Format("Prepare Trade Service Hub for {0}", TradeActivitySignalRURL), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);


                    HubConnectionNew = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(TradeActivitySignalRURL).Build();
                    HubConnectionNew.Closed += StockPusherHubDisconnect;
                    var Connect = StockPusherHubConnection_Connect();
                    Connect.Wait();

                    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Test calling Hub Active operation", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);

                    var Response = HubConnectionNew.InvokeAsync<bool>("Active").Result;
                    if (!Response)
                    {
                        HubConnectionNew = null;
                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Problem calling Hub Active operation", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
                        HubConnected = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Successfully called Hub Active operation", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
                        Res = true;
                        HubConnected = true;
                        HubConnectionNew.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100000);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Test calling Hub Active operation", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);

                    var Response = HubConnectionNew.InvokeAsync<bool>("Active").Result;
                    if (!Response)
                    {
                        HubConnectionNew = null;
                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Problem calling Hub Active operation", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
                        HubConnected = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Successfully called Hub Active operation", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
                        Res = true;
                        HubConnected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Res;
        }

        public virtual void TradingClientHubConnection_Closed()
        {
            StopHubConnection();
        }

        protected virtual void StopHubConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                if (HubConnectionNew != null && HubConnectionNew.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
                {
                    //HubConnectionNew.StopAsync().Wait();
                    lock (PreparingHub)
                    {
                        HubConnectionNew = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                HubConnected = false;
            }
        }

        private void StopTradeClientInterface()
        {
            try
            {
                StopHubConnection();
            }
            finally { }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// activate trading services        
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual bool ActivateTradeClientInterface()
        {
            bool bRes = false;

            if (!ActivatingTradeInterface)
            {
                try
                {
                    ActivatingTradeInterface = true;

                    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("oiTrader Client", "Attempt to connect to Trader Hub", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);

                    if (PrepareTradeActivityHub())
                    {
                        bRes = true;
                        Action TestRequestResult = TestApp;
                        HubConnectionNew.On("TestOp", TestRequestResult);
                        //For test
                        HubConnectionNew.On("TestOp", () =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Receive a TestOp message from the server");
                        });

                    }
                    else
                        StopHubConnection();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    StopHubConnection();
                }
                finally { ActivatingTradeInterface = false; }
            }
            else
                bRes = HubConnected;

            return bRes;
        }

        protected virtual Task StockPusherHubDisconnect(Exception arg)
        {
            StockPusherHubConnection_Connect().Wait();

            return null;
        }

        protected virtual async Task StockPusherHubConnection_Connect()
        {
            Exception exception = null;
            Exception except = null;

            try
            {
                if (HubConnectionNew != null)
                {
                    lock (PreparingHub)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", string.Format("Attempt to connect to Hub for {0}", Connection), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);

                        var HubConnect = HubConnectionNew?.StartAsync();
                        HubConnect?.Wait();
                        HubConnect?.ContinueWith(
                            task =>
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (task != null && task.IsFaulted)
                                    {
                                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", "Problem connecting to Hub for", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
                                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", task.Exception.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);

                                        exception = task?.Exception;
                                        except = exception?.InnerException;
                                        while (except != null)
                                        {
                                            except = except?.InnerException;
                                            if (except != null)
                                                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Support", except.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch { }
                            }
                        ).Wait();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        protected virtual void StopStockPusher()
        {
            try
            {
                if (HubConnectionNew != null && HubConnectionNew.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
                    HubConnectionNew.StopAsync();
            }
            catch { }

            HubConnectionNew = null;
        }

        protected void CallCheckActivated()
        {
            if (ClientHubActiveated != null) ClientHubActiveated();
        }
        #endregion //"Operations"
    }
}

2.MessageBackgroundService.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace TestClientServer
{
    public class MessageBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<TheHub> _hubContext;

        public MessageBackgroundService(IHubContext<TheHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);

                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("TestOp", cancellationToken: stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}

3.Startup.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestClientServer
{                  
    internal class Startup
    {
        #region Properties&Attributes
        public static string ListenPort { get; private set; }
        public static string TargetURL { get; private set; }
        private static string PolicyName { get { return "Trading Client Policy"; } }
        #endregion Properties&Attributes

        #region Lifetime
        static Startup()
        {
#if DEBUG
            ListenPort = "20";
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("HUB URL {0}", ListenPort));
#else
            ListenPort = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TradeClientSignalRURL"];
#endif

            TargetURL = string.Format("http://localhost:{0}", ListenPort);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("orderIT HUB listenining on {0}", TargetURL));
        }

        #endregion Lifetime

        #region Operations   
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();

            services.AddCors(o =>
            {
                o.AddDefaultPolicy(b =>
                {
                    b.WithOrigins(TargetURL)
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });

            //services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

            services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
                //hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
                //hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            });
            // Register MessageBackgroundService
            services.AddHostedService<MessageBackgroundService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseSwagger();
                //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "oiStockPusherSite v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(PolicyName);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                //endpoints.MapControllers(); 
                endpoints.MapHub<TheHub>("/TestHub", options =>
                {
                    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling; // you may also need this
                });
            });
        }

        #endregion Operations
    }
}

4.TheHub
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace TestClientServer
{
    public class TheHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub
    {
        bool IsDisposed = true;
        private Task CallTask;
        public TheHub()
        {  
            // Remove the code       
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            IsDisposed = true;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            IsDisposed = false;
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public void PostMessage(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsDisposed)
                Clients?.All.SendAsync("TestOp");                                                                        
        }

        public bool Active() => true;
    }
}

